# Writing file to Application Data Folder on Add-ons from Google App Script server code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

As mentioned in this [document](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata) about storing application data, I would like to make it possible from a Google App Script Add-on server code.

I was able to create an arbitrary file into my google root drive folder this way.

```
  DriveApp.createFile('Test', 'Test content');
```

But was not able to figure out how to create it into (hidden) app data folder:

```
var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById("appDataFolder");
var file = dir.createFile('Test', 'Test content');
```

Receiving "Access denied" by executing it.

I guess I have to apply this following scope to my app but do not know how apply it on a google app script.

Scope: *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata*

Drive API is well activated.

[image: Advanced google services]

It would be nice if I could update these scopes (File>Project Properties menu):

[image: Project properties scopes]

Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: I have also tried directly with Drive API call instead of native as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)  but at the end get the logical message "The current scope does not allow use of the appdata folder"

Comment: I just added a feature request for a helper function that would do this, as well as allow the script editor to manage the permission more rationally, please star/up vote if you concur: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6592

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I am looking for the same...

Comment: Does your script have an `appsscript.json` file?  You can add the necessary scope (assuming you know what it is, they are largely undocumented I've found) to the `"oauthScopes": ["...","..."]` array in that object.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Users have to explicitly grant your Add-on access to the private AppData folder. And currently that's only achievable by setting up an OAuth2 flow.</s>

**EDIT** As of November 2017, Apps Script now supports explicit OAuth scopes. There is no longer a need to set up a custom OAuth flow, simply set the desired OAuth scope in the manifest file (as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes)) to request access to a user's App Data Folder.

---

Here's a video that provides a good overview of how OAuth2 works (independent of Apps Script)

[OAuth 2.0: An Overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPbvxxslDTU)

---

If you're up to the task, you can review Google's [OAuth2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and figure out how to implement it for your use case, but you're better off leveraging the "official" [OAuth2 library for Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2).

Here's another video that covers OAuth flows for Add-ons using said library:

[OAuth2 flows in Add-ons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlHaLVvneV4&feature=youtu.be&t=890)

Note: Make sure that you use the appropriate scope(s) in your flow. In this case you only need to use one; `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`

---

Also, if you're looking for some code implementing an OAuth flow to access the App Data folder check out this github repo from Spencer Easton:

[Apps-Script-Appfolder-Library](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Appfolder-Library)

---

*The 2nd video is from [Totally Unscripted](https://sites.google.com/view/totallyunscripted/home), a vlog hosted by app script devs from the [Google+ App Script community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769). Check it out, its a great resource for App Script development.*

Answer (score -1):

You've enabled Drive v2 API and use the alias `appDataFolder` which is for Drive v3. That may have contributed to the issue you're encountering.

If you'll be using v2, try to change the alias to `appfolder`. Hopefully this has been of help to you.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for replying but still same issue "Access denied: DriveApp."

Comment: The Drive API version is not the issue. It has to do with the particular scope associated with the appDataFolder (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata). This scope has to be explicitly granted by the user and currently that can only be done by setting up an OAuth flow.